# tableView editing delegate method not working(Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0)

Tags: ios, uitableview

'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (6) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (6), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

```
->@property (nonatomic ,strong)  NSMutableArray *name;

    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame viewName:(NSInteger)viewDecide datasourceName:(NSMutableArray *)nameRef  
    {

    }
```

when i intialize the above MutableArray in this class
like

```
self.name=[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];
```

then using table view editing delegate method , every thing works fine , when i click the button the table goes in edited mode with deletion and insertion.

but when i initialize the same array with data source which i passed in above method . the data inside the tableview render proprely but when i click the edit button its crash.

note:- i used 
 for row count-

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return[self.name count];
}
```

and for inserting

```
[strongSelf.tableViewDataView1 insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0], nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];

 and for deleting i used

 [strongSelf.tableViewDataView1 deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0], nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
```

:-`strongSelf` is used because this happening inside a block.

Comment: This is because you are calling the insert part without actually adding the items to your array, so the value you are returning in `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` is not increasing but you are telling the tableView to insert a row.

Comment: yes , i got it  just a moment ago  but thanks yes i have to change the count when edit button clicked Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Your are removing the item from the table , not from your array. You have to remove the same from the array so that the count will remain same.